# How to convert SHA1 to array[5] of unsigned long ints?

Tags: c++, arrays, converters, sha1, unsigned-integer

For the purposes of library/subsystem that I use I have to convert SHA1 (calculated with use of e.g. opensll) to 5 element array of unsigned long ints (32 bits variables) or create the aforementioned SHA1-5-long-array by myself.

Reason:

`SHA1 (160 bits) = 5 x unsigned long int (32 bits)`

I think that first solution will be better so here is my question: how should I go around this task? Read byte/bit by byte/bit and then create unsigned long ints from it and put it in the array or is there a different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHA1 produces a 20 byte hash-value. In openssl it returns an `unsigned char*`. I'm guessing you can use a `union` of `unsigned char[20]` and `uint32_t[5]` and use the chars for easy byte access:

```
union mysha1{
    uint32_t shaint[5];
    unsigned char shachar[20];
};
```

Add to that a bunch of operators (indexing for example) and you are good to go.

If you wanna keep it crude and simple you can do a `memcpy` between the SHA1 output and your `uint32_t[5]`, though.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me:) Maybe someone else will come up with competing solution.

Comment: Well another solution will be "reinterpret_cast", but I'm pretty sure that it will break strict aliasing.